# does a class retain value after it is returned

Tags: php, pdo

Not 100% what my question should actually be, please do not be harsh on me if my inexperience  says Super Noob, but I have this class function that partially works and I can't seem to come up with a answer the Noob in me says dummy after you return the value it is gone never to be re used. with that being said here is the function and the code that reacts with it, and my questions is can the value be retained and be used after return? And irregaurdless can someone help me get this to work it retrieves the ads and displays them, but will not any way I have tried record the impressions. Please ignore my typos just got vision back and it is not perfect. The Function:
        function getRandomTextAds() {

```
    $sql = "SELECT
                ad_id,
                ad_client_id,
                ad_title,
                ad_url,
                ad_body,
                ad_link
            FROM
                text_ads
            WHERE
                status=1
                AND deleted=0
            ORDER BY
                rand()
            LIMIT 0, 5";

            $getBusyOn = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

            $getBusyOn->execute();

            $OKresult = $getBusyOn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $resultIsarray = array();

    return $OKresult;

    $initialize = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM text_ads_activity WHERE ad_id = ?AND ad_client_id = ?");
$initialize->bindValue(1, $ad_id);
$initialize->bindValue(2, $ad_client_id);
$initialize->execute();

if($initialize->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) == 0) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO text_ads_activity (
                    ad_id,
                    ad_view_cnt,
                    ad_activity_month,
                    ad_activity_year
                ) values (
                    ?,
                    1,
                    ?,
                    ?
                )";

            $isCommand = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $isCommand->bindValue(1, $ad_id);
            $isCommand->bindValue(2, date("m"));
        $isCommand->bindValue(3, date("Y"));

            $isCommand->execute();

            } else {

$sql = "UPDATE text_ads_activity SET
                ad_view_cnt = ad_view_cnt+1,
                ad_activity_month = ?,
                ad_activity_year = ?
            WHERE
                ad_id = ?
                AND ad_client_id = ?
                AND ad_activity_month = ?
                AND ad_activity_year = ?";

        $doOrElse = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $doOrElse->bindValue(1, date("m"));
        $doOrElse->bindValue(2, date("Y"));
        $doOrElse->bindValue(3, $ad_id);
        $doOrElse->bindValue(4, $ad_client_id);
        $doOrElse->bindValue(5, date("m"));
        $doOrElse->bindValue(6, date("Y"));

            $doOrElse->execute();
            }
        }
```

And now the section of code it interacts with

```
$resultIsarray = $siteSys->getRandomTextAds();
    $text_ad_count   = count($resultIsarray);


    foreach ($resultIsarray as $OKresult) {
    $ad_link = isset($OKresult['ad_link']) ? $OKresult['ad_link'] : '';
    $ad_title = isset($OKresult['ad_title']) ? $OKresult['ad_title'] : '';
    $ad_body = isset($OKresult['ad_body']) ? $OKresult['ad_body'] : '';
    $ad_url = isset($OKresult['ad_url']) ? $OKresult['ad_url'] : '';
    $ad_client_id = isset($OKresult['ad_client_id']) ? $OKresult['ad_client_id'] : '';
    $ad_id = isset($OKresult['ad_id']) ? $OKresult['ad_id'] : '';

                    <li align="center"><div id="text-ad-table">
                    <span class="heading"><a href="<?php echo $ad_link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $ad_title; ?></a></span>
                    <span class="col1"><?php echo $ad_body; ?></span>
                    <span class="full-url"><?php echo $ad_url; ?></span>
                    </div></li><!-- eof #table -->

                    }
```

I hope I did as required, Thank You in Advance.....

Answer (score 0):

return affects not the value, but the code.  when you return, none more lines in that function will be executed.  The return doesn't just send the result back, it hand-carries it and returns with it.

You can either update the impressions before you return (slows the page response time), or write the page contents, flush the output, and record the impression after the response has been sent on its way, or you could save the information and have a system take care of recording the impressions in the background, like a job queue or a dedicated thread or something.

Comment: I figured that something like that, TYVM! But now how to make background process? LOL on a new hunt now.